# How to layout views so that radiogroup could be used?

Tags: android, layout, radio-button

Right now i have this layout (horizontal relative layouts inside vertical linear layout) , but i need radiobuttons instead of checkboxes (user must be able to choose just one option).

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/flag_en"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
        android:text="English"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dip"            
         />

         <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

   </RelativeLayout>    

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/flag_dk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
        android:text="Dansk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dip"        
         />

         <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

        </RelativeLayout>
         <Button
          android:id="@+id/ang_btn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="ang"
         />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Problem is that RadioGroup must be placed inside linear layout (not relative), so i can't use above layout.

How can i achieve the same layout (multiple rows, 3 colums, radiobuttons in the third column) and also use radiogroup with radiobuttons?

EDIT:
I tried Robby Pond's solution (below) and i get this:
[image]

I could used that if i could put some space between radiobutton and it's drawableLeft. I managed to get some space between drawableLeft and text with android:drawablePadding="10dip" (not seen on my last screenshot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use radio group and radio button and use android:drawableLeft on the RadioButton for the images.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RadioGroup ...>
        <RadioButton ... android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_en" android:text="English" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @DixieFlatline Yeah looks like you can either use drawablePadding or just added spaces to the beginning of the text. Kinda annoying that you cannot specify that you want the radio button to be on the right instead of the left.